# Do we need a life jacket for our almost 2-year-old when we go to the beach?

Tags: travel, swimming, water

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What should we pack when going camping with an infant?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/2105/what-should-we-pack-when-going-camping-with-an-infant)

My family and I are going to the beach this July.  It will be the first trip to the beach for my son, my daughter, and my husband.  My daughter will be a few days shy of her second birthday when we go, and my husband insists that she needs a life jacket.  We obviously have no intention of letting her go near the water on her own, and when we do go in the water it will be shallow water and we'll be holding her the entire time.

I see my husband's point.  Yes, there's the possibility that something *could* happen and she *could* sprint away from us and into the water without us, or we *could* lose our hold on her and drop her I guess.  With four adults (my parents are coming, too), I just don't think it's that much of a concern.

However, I agreed that I would post to the community and agree to the consensus.  So:  life jacket or no life jacket?

If you recommend life jacket, could you point me towards a place where I can find a life jacket for a child who weighs <25 lbs?  My daughter is VERY small for her age and we *might* hit 25 pounds by her birthday--maybe.  She's 21ish pounds right now.

Comment: As-is, this is worded a bit subjectively (e.g. you're actively polling for consensus on opinion). After discussing this with @TorbenGundtofte-Bruun we feel this should be closed as a duplicate, as [this other question](http://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/2105/what-should-we-pack-when-going-camping-with-an-infant) has lots of useful information on life jackets that may answer your question. If not, please consider re-phrasing this question to be more specific and objective, and ping me once you have made the edits and we can see about re-opening it.

Comment: Meanwhile, I will ping you in [chat] with some resources to help you find appropriate life jackets, in response to the last part of this question (shopping questions are off-topic, which is why I won't answer here, but I think I found some information that you might find useful).