# Going hiking with an infant - how to prepare?

Tags: infant, health, safety, travel

We are going on a vacation with our 9 month old. As we love hiking, we have decided to try to hike with our little one. We chose mountains with rather easy paths and at most 1000 meters above sea level.

We would like to be as prepared as possible. We have decent experience hiking on our own, but it's the first time we're going with our child.

What things should we take, consider, prepare before the vacation and before each trip?

*some useful hints can be found in [What should we pack when going camping with an infant?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/2105/what-should-we-pack-when-going-camping-with-an-infant) but that question is about entirely different destination*

Comment: Will you hike a trail and camp along the way. Or make dayhikes from a central location? Is the child used to making day hikes? In my opinion it is very important to take it slow and allow enough time for the kid to just do its thing.

Comment: Central location; we will not try push ourselves or the baby. Our LO is used to long walks in a stroller, we've taken her for a few shorter walks in a carry cot, which she seemed to enjoy.

Comment: I would  be extra diligent in doing all the 'safety things' like telling forest rangers where you plan to hike and camp, bringing emergency supplies even on easy day trips and so forth (I know I didn't always do this day hiking adults only).

Comment: LO? masl? What do these abbrs mean?

Comment: Where and at what time of the year will you be hiking?

Comment: Just please don t do as I see too many parents do: Adult with hiking boots, clothe for hiking etc... and infant in sandals, short, without hats...

Answer (score 5):

I took my 12 month old on a short (but uneven / rocky) hike near Tahoe last year. If I were to do any sort of hiking again, I would definitely recommend the following:

- Wearable Baby Carrier with some sort of waist harness - I used the Baby Bjorn Mesh Baby Carrier Active for the hike. With the baby carrier properly adjusted I felt like my little one's weight was close to my core and off my shoulders. This made it easier for me to hike for a longer period of time and equipped to deal with uneven terrain. He was in front of me so I could avoid brush and branches from hitting him in the face which was a plus.
- Walking stick - I didn't have one at the beginning of the hike, but found a solid stick along the way and I felt like it was very helpful. Even though the carrier kept my little one's weight in the right place, every now and then when I was extending for a foothold or navigating through rocks, that walking stick kept me balanced, confident, and safe.

Hope that helps and that you enjoy your trip!

Comment: For something strenuous like hiking, it would be important to use an ergonomic baby carrier, such as a [Mei Tai](http://www.meitaibaby.com/) or an [Ergo](http://store.ergobaby.com/). Ergonomic in this case refers to the baby's comfort, not the wearer. Bjorns, despite their popularity, can cause [hip dysplasia](http://hipdysplasia.org/developmental-dysplasia-of-the-hip/prevention/baby-carriers-seats-and-other-equipment/) and, based on how my daughter acted when we used one for long walks, not very comfortable.

Answer (score 1):

Having the experience behind, here's a list of things to remember when preparing:

**General trip preparations**

- a sufficient supply of diapers, unless shops are certain to be available
- a set of clothes 1.5x times larger than the minimum for the amount of days you will be spending on the trip (feel free to modify the multiplier if you feel your baby is cleaner/dirtier than the usual baby)
- a choice of clothes suitable for the expected weather
- a few smaller packages of wet wipes - sufficient for the whole trip (larger ones may be heavy to carry in a bag/bagpack)
- a portable travel bed to which the baby is used to (or at least accustomed with a few days before, in a comfortable and safe environment)
- food for the baby for at least a few days into the trip; make sure you have enough or a shop available at your destination
- a supply of plastic bags or other dirty-diaper smell-hazard-protection equipment for a few days
- a portable changing mat
- a baby bath tub (unless one is available where you are staying)
- a supply of baby skin/health care products
- an electronic thermometer
- at least a small supply fever reducing medicine for the baby
- bandages (bandaid?), sterile cloth, skin disinfectant spray (antiseptics)
- a large, comfortable car is strongly suggested
- a baby carriage/stroller
- blankets, tetra diapers, etc.

**Hiking**

- a comfortable baby carrier; make sure the hips are in a natural, spread position
- the weather changes rapidly in the mountains - get a raincoat and make sure the carrier is rain-ready
- good, comfortable, pre-worn hiking boots for both parents
- a comfortable bagpack for other baby stuff
- at least one meal more than you expect will be needed for the baby to eat on the way
- a change of clothes/additional clothes in case it gets colder
- dress yourselves and the baby in layers; add or remove when necessary